# Make a div always on top using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple HTML/JavaScript project. In this I have a main `div`, in this `div` I have another `div` which is not visible initially.

```
<div>
    <div class="warning" id="time-alert" style="visibility:hidden">
        <span style="font-weight:bold">your time is up To extend the time click on
            extend button.
        <input type="button" id="extend-btn" onclick="clickaction()" value="Extend">
    </div>
    <div class="create pull-right">
        <button id="btn-create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
            onClick="openmodal()">open modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks on open modal button, a Bootstrap modal pops up. Now I am making that time-alert `div` visible continuously on 2 minutes interval by JavaScript. When I am on home page it's working fine but if model has already opened on the screen, the alert `div` is not showing above the modal. Can you please tell me how can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: You have `onclick="click-action()"` as the click handling for your input. The value of the attribute is interpreted as a string of JavaScript. In JavaScript, variable names can't have hyphen in them. You probably meant to type `clickAction()` or `clickaction()`

Comment: By model, you mean modal? and this is not the minimum amount of code to answer this question.

Comment: okey the only thing i want to know is how can i show a division always top of all screen which are opened at that time and z-index is not working

Comment: could you please add your fiddle code

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the HTML of your bootstrap modal **before** the "time alert" div. That way, the modal box should stay behind the time alert. You may want to add a z-index to the CSS of the time alert if need be.

Comment: yeh its working now but i cant put my model code before the alert is there any way to do it

Comment: Why can't you do that? Can you show me the full markup?